# Google Drive SDK - Is it possible to avoid user consent?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm attempting to setup a file on Google Drive that I can use to save configuration data to. This is in order to change this data in real time, as well as by multiple users with the added benefit keeping the version history.

I have setup an app on a test account and have a client ID and client Secret. I can currently successfully upload/download files, but I still need to give consent the first time to generate the OAuth token.

So my question: Is it possible to use the combination of the clientID and clientSecret to skip the authentication process completely?

I've tried to mess around with the scope of the app as well as different types of credentials, but haven't been able to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, Drive isn't designed for this use case - it is meant for personal/corporate files for individual users, not for serving apps.

You could generate a refresh token that could be baked into your app, however that is exceptionally ill-advised since anyone who grabs the refresh token would then have access to your account (including deleting the configuration file).

For iOS & Android: You would be a lot better served looking into more suitable services, such as Google's [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/), which is designed precisely for this.

> Firebase Remote Config is a cloud service that lets you change the behavior and appearance of your app without requiring users to download an app update. When using Remote Config, you create in-app default values that control the behavior and appearance of your app. Then, you can later use the Firebase console to override in-app default values for all app users or for segments of your userbase. Your app controls when updates are applied, and it can frequently check for updates and apply them with a negligible impact on performance.

For web: You could just use the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).

> Store and sync data with our NoSQL cloud database. Data is synced across all clients in realtime, and remains available when your app goes offline.